# Can you set seperate colors for different axes in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've got a simple chart.js chart with dual axes.  To improve readability, I'd like to color coordinate the chart & scale data.  Is this possible?

For example, in my sample below, I'd like to have the temp values on left axis shown in red and the SG values on the right axis shown in blue.

I've tried adding `fontColor` and `scaleFontColor` options under the specific axis options, but no luck.

Here is my code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');

var chartData = {
  labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri'],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Temp F',
    yAxisID: 'F',
    display: true,
    fill: false,
    borderColor: '#ff6384', //red
    data: [100, 96, 84, 76, 69]
  }, {
    //type: 'line',
    label: 'Gravity',
    yAxisID: 'G',
    display: true,
    fill: false,
    borderColor: '#36a2eb', //blue
    data: [1.07, 1.055, 1.020, 1.015, 1.012]
  }]
};

var myChart = new Chart(canvas, {
  type: 'line',
  data: chartData,
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Mmm Beer!'
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        id: 'F',
        position: 'left',
        scaleFontColor: '#ff6384', //red
        ticks: {
          suggestedMin: 32,
          suggestedMax: 100
        }
      }, {
        id: 'G',
        position: 'right',
        ticks: {
          suggestedMin: 1,
          suggestedMax: 1.1
        },
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false, // only want the grid lines for one axis to show up
        },
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: @Adnan, thx for the edit.  I didn't know you could put runnable snippets directly in the question.

Comment: My pleasure! It's a new feature of Stackoverflow to add runnable code snippet. However, I don't understand what you are trying to do.  Do you want to change the color  of the grid-lines?

Comment: @AdnanSharif I'm trying to change the colors on the scale labels on the left & right yAxes.  For example, have the temp values on left axis in red and the SG values on the right axis in blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have solved the problem. As you are trying to change the color of both Y axis values. You need to add `fontColor` property inside `ticks` object for the specific `yAxes`.  Then assign any color value you want to `fontColor` property of `ticks` object.

Find the changes here

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');

var chartData = {
  labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri'],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Temp F',
    yAxisID: 'F',
    display: true,
    fill: false,
    borderColor: '#ff6384', //red
    data: [100, 96, 84, 76, 69]
  }, {
    //type: 'line',
    label: 'Gravity',
    yAxisID: 'G',
    display: true,
    fill: false,
    borderColor: '#36a2eb', //blue
    data: [1.07, 1.055, 1.020, 1.015, 1.012]
  }]
};

// @ts-ignore
var myChart = new Chart(canvas, {
  type: 'line',
  data: chartData,
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Mmm Beer!'
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        id: 'F',
        position: 'left',
        ticks: {
          fontColor: '#ff6384', //red
          suggestedMin: 32,
          suggestedMax: 100
        }
      }, {
        id: 'G',
        position: 'right',
        ticks: {
          fontColor: '#36a2eb', //blue
          suggestedMin: 1,
          suggestedMax: 1.1
        },
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false, // only want the grid lines for one axis to show up
        },
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <canvas class=".content" id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Hope, this will help you. Thanks!

Comment: Bingo!   I'm curious: did you find this documented somewhere, or did you just experiment with it?

Comment: It is documented [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#tick-configuration)